# Pagespeed insight low mobile index very low but page very fast

Tags: pagespeed-insights

How is it possible that mobile index for my pages (magento2) is very low (30) and it says that it takes about 8.6 seconds before loading.

While page is flashing i performance (also on mobile)

https://www.tricotstoffen.nl/tricot-giraffe-olifant-zebra.html

Answer (score 0):

Because pagespeed-insights uses Emulated 3G network throttling, while your mobile is on 4G/Wifi. Please check my question: [Why emulated 3g on pagespeed-insights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512464/why-emulated-3g-on-pagespeed-insights)