# Why emulated 3g on pagespeed-insights?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

As i checked on google, pagespeed measures mobile and desktop sites using "Emulated 3G network". As per some GSMA report from 2016 that 75% or users are on 2G/3G networks.

Thats almost 2019 year and many users are on 4G now, so reports are useless.

Can someone tell Google that either they should use "No throttling" or add switcher for 4G network.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not supposed to be a way of getting people to contact a company on your behalf.  That's your job.

Comment: there is no official contacts on pagespeed-insights page. They refer to stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, to answer questions you might have and help solve problems.  We are not a line to customer support.  Sorry, we aren't going to call Google for you and give them a heads up.  They have some smart people working for them and know 4g is more common now.

Comment: Here you go:  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/webmasters

Comment: Yes, Google refers to Stack Overflow for *specific, answerable questions*, and refers to their [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pagespeed-insights-discuss) for feedback and general discussion. Either way, this type of question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Created discussion on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pagespeed-insights-discuss/J14IEWlnRVI

Answer (score 0):

Per GSM report for 2017, 71% of Global users are on 2G/3G network. That number drops to 32% for North America and 59% for Europe. While we are definitely moving toward 4G dominance (predicted by 2025), it seems too early to ignore such a big part of consumers.

Comment: But its time to add possibility to change throtting. Or you want to keep 3G up to 2025? If you keep 3G as one option pagespeed-insights became useless tool.

Answer (score 0):

If your business have customers buying from 3g networks then take page insights data into consideration. Otherwise just don't look at them, they are misleading for most use cases. Google want us to believe we live in Africa all together. Note they are also emulate a moto 4g, a mobile phone from 2016 for their tests. Another fail for the modern era.